# Where to enable Https with Laravel Mix

Tags: laravel, https, laravel-mix

Why is there no secure option for the mix function like there is for the asset function? For now I just copied the helper and wrote my own mix_secure function but I am surprised nobody else stumbled over that yet? Sadly the asset function has no cache busting...

Any thoughts/ideas?

Cheers,

Robin

Comment: Why not using the versioning for cache busting?

Answer (score 4):

> Why is there no secure option for the mix function like there is for the asset function?

Because `mix()` returns only the [URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier) as opposed to [URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL)

Therefore if used just by itself in your blade template

```html
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

It will render as

```html
<script src="/js/app.js?id=c5ac0d032c3d7fe2f10e"></script>
```

and the browser will pick up whatever scheme (HTTP or HTTPS) and the domain name it's being served from. I can't think of a situation when you'd want to serve an asset with a different scheme. More over nowadays you'd want to serve everything over HTTPS.

Now if you want to build a full URL to an asset there are two built-in functions [`asset()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/a61a234a69079b9509757b19133c7f4c358b7be1/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php#L124) and [`secure_asset()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/a61a234a69079b9509757b19133c7f4c358b7be1/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php#L720) which do exactly what their names imply:

```
>>> asset(mix('js/app.js'))
=> "http://domain.dev/js/app.js?id=c5ac0d032c3d7fe2f10e"
>>> secure_asset(mix('js/app.js'))
=> "https://domain.dev/js/app.js?id=c5ac0d032c3d7fe2f10e"
```

> Sadly the asset function has no cache busting...

Again you're looking at this wrong. `mix()` is responsible for URI not the `asset()` and it will use the asset manifest `public/mix-manifest.json`, which is generated when you compile your assets,  to produce a proper path. In order to leverage the automatic cache busting you need to version your assets at compile time with laravel mix

```js
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .version(); // You need to version assets if you want automatic cache busting
```

then prior to mix v1.0.0 the filename of an asset would contain the hash

```
/js/app-c5ac0d032c3d7fe2f10e.js
```

with mix v1.0.0 and up the hash is now in a query parameter

```
/js/app.js?id=c5ac0d032c3d7fe2f10e
```

Further reading [Versioning / Cache Busting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix#versioning-and-cache-busting)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Interestingly mix does return a full URL for me and not just the URI (which would indeed solve the problem). And if I look at the Laravel source code for the mix function the last line of it actually calls the asset function `return new HtmlString(asset($manifestDirectory.$manifest[$path]));`. That's why I built a `mix_secure` which is a copy of the mix function but has the last line with the secure flag for the asset function `return new HtmlString(asset($manifestDirectory.$manifest[$path], true));`. This solution works for me but I am surprised that it's not built in!?